# Can I use @switch and Enumerations?

Tags: scala, enums, switch-statement, pattern-matching, scala-2.11

Can I use switch-case for pattern matching on enumerations?

I tried

```
import scala.annotation.switch

object Foo extends Enumeration {
  val First = Value
  val Second = Value
  val Third = Value
}

object Main {
  def foo(x: Foo.Value) = (x: @switch) match {
    case Foo.First => 1
    case Foo.Second => 2
    case Foo.Third => 3
  }
}
```

but get the following warning (Scala 2.11.4):

```
warning: could not emit switch for @switch annotated match
  def foo(x: Foo.Value) = (x: @switch) match {
```

I then tried defining the enumeration in Java instead, since Java's `enum`s are different than Scala's `Enumeration`. Still no luck.

It `@switch` pattern matching only available on primitive types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete Regis answer, in Scala In Depth, Joshua Suereth states that the following conditions must be true for Scala to apply the tableswitch optimization:

1. The matched value must be a known integer.
2. The matched expression must be “simple.” It can’t contain any type checks, if statements, or extractors.
3. The expression must also have its value available at compile time.
4. There should be more than two case statements.

Foo object does not match to any of above criteria though it is not a subject for tableswitch optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the `switch` annotation is to make sure that your match is compiled into a `tableswitch` or `lookupswitch` JVM instruction. Those instructions only work on ints, which means that the `switch` annotation will only have any effect on types that can safely fit in an `Int`. Meaning `Int` itself  as well as `Char`, `Byte`, `Short` and `Boolean`. In addition, the values you match against have to be literal values (as opposed to values stored in a `val`). Given that an `Enumeration` is a reference value, they are not compatible with `switch` annotation. The restriction about literal values actually means that there is probably no way to use this ennotation for `Short` and `Byte`, for purely syntactic reasons as there is no support for literal shorts and bytes in scala: you have to use a literal int along with a type ascription as in `123: Byte`, but this is not accepted as a pattern.
So that leaves only `Int`, `Char` and `Boolean` as valid types (the usefulness of using `@switch` for a boolean value is dubious to say the least)

Comment: Though Java's switch-case on an enum results in a `tableswitch` / `lookupswitch`. But yes, it does seems my options are (1) write Java, or (2) as you said, use a primitive type.

Comment: The important distinction here is that Java enums have built-in language support, while Scala enumeration are purely defined in the standard library